# Pass Array to SSH Connection

Tags: debian, ssh, array

How can I pass an array across the ssh connection.

I have an array formed thus:

```
declare -a target_array=(
    "item1 -p12345 -r"
    "item2 -p65677 -e"
)
```

I then need to pass it to an ssh connection as follows:

```
ssh $server target_array=${target_array[@]}" "bash -s" <<TARGETSCRIPT
    echo "hello"
TARGETSCRIPT
```

But this just gives me the error:

```
bash: -p12345: command not found
```

What is the best way to do this? I've tried with and without `{}`, with and without `[@]` but nothing seems to work.

(n.b. that `echo hello` is just a placeholder for an 800 line script that makes use of the target_array).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't put the array as the first argument to `ssh` behind the host. It will be evaluated as the command and obviously fails. If you really need to do this, you should add it into the "script" like this:

```
ssh $server "bash -s" <<TARGETSCRIPT
    target_array=("${target_array[@]}")
    echo ${target_array[@]}
    echo "hello"
TARGETSCRIPT
```

Also encapsulating the array properly is useful to make sure the array stays the same on the other end.

Comment: Those `${target_array[@]}` are expanded by the _local_ shell. Also what if elements contain things like `$(rm -rf ~)`?

Answer (score 2):

```
remote_code=$(cat << 'EOF'
echo Hello
for i in "${!target_array[@]}"; do
  echo "$i -> ${target_array[i]}"
done
EOF
)

ssh server bash << EOF
$(declare -p target_array)
$remote_code
EOF
```

The remote  shell will see on stdin something like:

```
declare -a target_array='([0]="item1 -p12345 -r" [1]="item2 -p65677 -e")'
echo Hello
for i in "${!target_array[@]}"; do
  echo "$i -> ${target_array[i]}"
done
```

To avoid clobbering the remote shell's stdin, and assuming your ssh and the remote sshd allows passing `LC_*` environment variables, you could also do:

```
LC_CODE="$(declare -p target_array)
$remote_code" ssh server 'bash -c '\''eval "$LC_CODE"'\'
```

If you know the login shell of the remote user is `bash`, you can simply do:

```
ssh server "$(declare -p target_array)
$remote_code"
```